# Add picture in premade powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I'm following [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303718) instructions, and this works well.

```
objSlide = objSlides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
```

this code fragment creates a new slide.

But Now I want to add a picture to a presentation that has already been set up.

So my question is how do I insert a picture on slide 15, without creating a new slide 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the example `objSlide = objSlides[15]` will give you the reference to the 15th slide. The rest is the same as the example.